# ReactJS, i have one key that is not unique, how to make it only as one key per row?

Tags: reactjs

The problem lies upon having a duplicate key due to 2 indexes in a field in the JSON data. 
There is a total of 58 issues, however there is 59 rows due to one issue having 2 indexes which creates a new row with duplicate key value which is 33 as shown in the image.

```
  {this.state.acceptedTickets && this.state.acceptedTickets.issues && Object.keys(this.state.acceptedTickets.issues).map((issue, i) =>
      (
        this.state.acceptedTickets && this.state.acceptedTickets.issues && this.state.acceptedTickets.issues[i].fields.customfield_11400 && Object.keys(this.state.acceptedTickets.issues[i].fields.customfield_11400).map((clientName, clientName_index)=>
          <td key={i}>
              {i + " "}
            {
              this.state.acceptedTickets.issues[i].fields.customfield_11400[clientName_index].value
            }
          </td>
        )
      ))}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: The thing is, there should be 58 rows not 59 rows

Comment: Even if i add i +1, it will display from 1 to 58 instead of 0 to 57

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are iterating over an array of arrays, and just using the index in the outer array as the key - which won't be unique if the inner array has length > 1.

Instead try: `key={`${i}-${clientName_index}`}`

Key just has to be a unique string.

```
{this.state.acceptedTickets && this.state.acceptedTickets.issues && Object.keys(this.state.acceptedTickets.issues).map((issue, i) =>
  (
    this.state.acceptedTickets && this.state.acceptedTickets.issues && this.state.acceptedTickets.issues[i].fields.customfield_11400 && Object.keys(this.state.acceptedTickets.issues[i].fields.customfield_11400).map((clientName, clientName_index)=>
      <td key={`${i}-${clientName_index}`}>
          {i + " "}
        {
          this.state.acceptedTickets.issues[i].fields.customfield_11400[clientName_index].value
        }
      </td>
    )
  ))}
```

Comment: It still seems to be printing 59 values instead of 58 :(

Comment: Is the outer array length 58, and one of the inner arrays has length 2 while the others have length 1? Then it makes sense why you are getting 59 items rendered - you are doing `.map()` of the inner array inside `.map()` of the outer array, so you end up with the total number of items in all inner arrays: `57 * 1 + 1 * 2`

Comment: Yeah, exactly, the outer array has length of 58, the inner array all have length of 1 except that key of 33 with length of 2 , i want to put all the values of key 33 in one line

Comment: So it would look like this **Air Canada , Air canada rouge** on one row so then i'd have 58 rows instead of 59 :/

Comment: Then you need to move the inner `.map()` inside the `<td>`, and you will end up putting the contents of the inner array into a single `<td>`.

Comment: I tried putting the inner .map() inside the td but it keeps giving me an error

Comment: Could you give an example and how to do this with proper syntax

Comment: ```
      <td key={`${i}-${clientName_index}`}>
{Object.keys(....customfield_11400).map((clientName_index) => ...customfield_11400[clientName_index].value).join(', ')}
      </td> ```